# Unable to get inherited gitlab CI/CD variables

Tags: variables, gitlab, continuous-integration

I would like to create a variable for all of my project located under a group.
I create a variable in this group

[image]

I go under a subgroup and check for CI/CD vars of this subgroup and my var isn't present

[image]

As it is said in gitlab documentation:

> Variables from subgroups are recursively inherited.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

Which step did I miss ?

Comment: When the doc said `recursively inherited`, it means the variable can be used in `gitlab-ci.yml` of every repository created under this group, It doesn't mean you can see it in CI/CD UI outside this group.

Answer (score 2):

You can't see inherited variables in subgroup variables.
But they can be seen in a project in a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Under the section where you can define the variables for the project there is a section "Group variables (inherited)". Here you should find your variable.

[image]

Comment: I haven't this section. And when I use an inherited var, it doesn't exists.

Comment: @Igm42 For me it was a result of looking for the variables in the group and not the project itself. Example:
AwesomeApp --> WebStuff --> WebServer1

. AwesomeApp is where I set the variable. I can not see it in the WebStuff group, but I could see the inherited variable in my WebServer1 project. Hope that helps clarify it.